# How to remove duplicates from an array object property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

How can I iterate through object properties and remove duplicates from an array that is the value of that object property?

Original object

```
var navObjects = {
    'Components': ['x', 'y', 'x'],
    'Document': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'q'],
    'Utilities': ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

Desired object

```
navObjects: {
    'Components': ['x', 'y'],
    'Document': ['z','q'],
    'Utilities': ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

What I've tried

```
for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(navObjects).length; i++) {

    let obj = Object.values(navObjects)[i];

    Object.values(obj).filter((item, index) => obj.indexOf(item) === index);
    console.log(obj);

}
```

The arrays remain unchanged after running this block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const navObjects = {
  'Components': ['x', 'y', 'x'],
  'Document': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'q'],
  'Utilities': ['a', 'b', 'c']
};

for (const key in navObjects) {
  navObjects[key] = [...new Set(navObjects[key])];
}

console.log(navObjects);
```

Comment: Nice. This wins.

Comment: This will only work if we assume that the object only has array members and we intend to remove duplicates for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to achieve your objective.

```
var newNavObjects = {}
var existObjects = {}
for(let key in navObjects) {
    let objects = navObjects[key];
    newNavObjects[key] = [];
    existObjects[key] = {};
    for(let object of objects) {
        if (!existObjects[key][object]) {
            existObjects[key][object] = 1;
            newNavObjects[key].push(object);
        }
    }
}
delete existObjects;
console.log(newNavObjects);
```

I create new variable for efficiency. If we use indexOf to check value inside array exist of not. It will heavier than we check an target variable key in this case existObjects. Still this not the best solution but this sure will do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Set` to remove duplicates and get `values()` in order to convert it back to an array, like:

```
(new Set(['z', 'z', 'z', 'q'])).values()
```

Let's make a `function` of it:

```
function removeDuplicates(input) {
    return (new Set(input)).values();
}
```

and then use it:

```
var navObjects = {
    'Components': removeDuplicates(['x', 'y', 'x']),
    'Document': removeDuplicates(['z', 'z', 'z', 'q']),
    'Utilities': removeDuplicates(['a', 'b', 'c'])
}
```

Comment: I wonder about the reason this answer was downvoted. I tested it and it worked. If someone would shed light on the reason, I would be grateful.